# Animating CAShapeLayer to follow the lline of UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I an trying to animate the stroke of a UIBezierPath, as if drawing with a pencil.

However, I am finding that the layer seems to be creating an entire shape by connecting my first and last points on the curve -- and this is not what I want. I simply want a line of stroke 2.0 to animate. Here is my code:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(20.0f, 20.f)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20.f, 200.f)];

CGFloat radius = 6.f;
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(20.f + radius, 200.f) radius:radius startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI/2 clockwise:NO];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(240, 200.f+radius)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(240.f, 480.f)];
[path stroke];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0;

[self.scrollView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
pathAnimation.duration = 4.f;
pathAnimation.fromValue = @(0.0f);
pathAnimation.toValue = @(1.0f);
pathAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:0.6 :0.3 :0.8 :0.45];
[shapeLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
```

and here is what it looks like:[image: I only want the red portion to be drawn. This is the portion that is animating]

Comment: Not sure if this is the 'correct' decision, but I got it to work by setting the fill color of the layer to be clear...